# C# variable resetting or not getting changed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a listview that I fill with 5 items (SELECT TOP 5 in SQL). Underneath is a button called "View all" that extends the listview by re-binding it and selecting every value in the table instead of just the top 5.

This works fine. However I need to vote on the items in this list as well, and this is where it doesn't work. When I vote I need to rebind the listview yet again. So to vote there is a few things I have to do.

1. Check if the listview is extended or not (if user has clicked "view all").
2. handle all the db-calls that handles the votes.
3. rebind the list so the user can see the change his/her vote made.

However step 1 is not working. When the user extends my listView I set boolean `extended=true`. And I check for this after vote. But for some reason the boolean always returns false.

Code:

Create the variable:

```
private Boolean extended = false;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
```

I extend the list by clicking "view all":

```
protected void LinkButtonviewFullCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String cmdText1 = "SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ([col] = @HFID) ORDER BY [rating] DESC"; //extend the list
   //This is where I bind the list using cmdText1
   extended = true; //never is true when I check in method below
}
```

I vote on something in the list and rebind it:

```
protected void BindList()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(extended);
    String cmdText1;
    if (extended == true)
    {
       cmdText1 = "SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ([col] = @HFID) ORDER BY [rating] DESC"; 
        //keep the list extended after vote
    }
    else
    {
       cmdText1 = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [table] WHERE ([col] = @HFID) ORDER BY [rating] DESC"; 
        //keep the list short after vote
    }
//Code for handeling cmds
}
```

I have tried not setting the Boolean to false when I create it since I thought that might be the issue, but that did not change anything. It still always return false. I do not understand, everything in that method gets run except the boolean change.

Comment: where do you set it to false?

Comment: @dotctor: On the first line of code in the question.  Where the value is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is stateless.  That is, your page-level code doesn't persist from one request to the next.  So every time a request is made to your page, the class is re-initialized from scratch.

So the value is `false` because it's initialized to `false`:

```
private Boolean extended = false;
```

In order to store a value between page requests you'll need to persist that value somewhere.  In cases like this a common approach could be to persist it to session state.  Something like this:

```
Session["extended"] = true;
```

Then when you need to read the value:

```
bool extended;
if (!bool.TryParse(Session["extended"], out extended))
{
    // value couldn't be parsed
}
// proceed with logic
```

Unlike WinForms where a Form object continues to exist, WebForms disposes of the Page after servicing any given request.  So the Page object is re-created each time.  Class-level values won't still be there.

Comment: @MrCharli3: Glad I could help!  Be aware that there are several different ways to persist values, each with their own pros and cons.  You might also use ViewState (or, more explicitly, a hidden form value on the page).  Or perhaps a database.  Maybe some application-level cache.  Etc.

Comment: I am more used to using hidden form value. So I will try this first. If it doesn't work Ill read up on the other options